# C - Program gives SEGFAULT with for-loop, but not without

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am doing a program which reads 3x3 matrices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { 
    int row;
    int col;
    long **tab;
} matr;

int SIZE = 3;

void *emalloc(size_t size) {
    void *memory = malloc(size);

    if (!memory) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to malloc.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return memory;
}

void file_to_matrix(FILE *path_matr, matr *m) {
    long **matrix = (long**) emalloc(SIZE * sizeof(long*));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) matrix[i] = (long*) emalloc(SIZE * sizeof(long));

    char line[4];
    fscanf(path_matr, " %[^\n]", line);

    // This code does not give SEGFAULT
    // for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    //  fscanf(path_matr, "%ld%ld%ld", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]);
    // }

    // The code below gives SEGFAULT
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            fscanf(path_matr, "%ld", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    m->row = SIZE;
    m->col = SIZE;
    m->tab = matrix;
}

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *path_matr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    /*Getting the matrices*/
    int n_matr; // Number of matrices
    fscanf(path_matr, "%d", &n_matr);
    matr *matrices = emalloc(n_matr * sizeof(matr));

    for (int i = 0; i < n_matr; i++) {
        file_to_matrix(path_matr, &matrices[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n_matr; i++)
        free(matrices[i].tab);
    free(matrices);
    fclose(path_matr);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice there are two for-loops in file_to_matrix function. One version gives segmentation fault, the other does not. Why? Funny thing is: if I enable -O2, both version works.

Compiled with gcc -std=c11 test.c -o test -g && ./test in.txt (gcc version 4.9.2).

in.txt:

```
3
∗∗∗
11 12 1444
21 22 23
31 32 33
∗∗∗
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
∗∗∗
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 31 33
∗∗∗
```

*P.S.: The code I posted here is part of another code, from which I removed some blocks (such as checking the number of arguments, fopen's return, etc) for simplicity. The issues I describe here also happens with the original code.*

Comment: Side issue: you are not freeing the memory you have allocated for your matrices (or closing `path_matr` or returning a value from `main()`).

Comment: I just compiled and ran both versions on gcc 8.1.0 x86_64. Everything is ok and both matrices are read correctly. Probably some buffer overflow leading to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're causing a buffer overflow with

```
char line[4];
fscanf(path_matr, " %[^\n]", line);
```

Try changing to

```
fscanf(path_matr, " %3[^\n]", line);
```

or mitigating the potential for overflow in some other way.

#### Character width

Ensure you are using `*` (unicode [0x2a](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002a/index.htm)) and not `∗` (unicode [0xE2 0x88 0x97](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2217/index.htm)) for the separators. The larger character width in the latter causes `scanf()` to terminate early. (When I copied and pasted the sample input on your question it included the wider character.)

When you do this the maximum field width specifier for `scanf()` isn't strictly necessary - but I would still use it anyway.

#### Optimization

When you increase optimization with `-O2` `matrix` is optimized out - so the program doesn't even try to write to it.

P.S.: you should check the return value from `fopen()`.

Comment: It seems changing to fscanf(path_matr, " %3[^\n]", line); indeed solved the segmentation fault. Do you have any idea why using the first version works?

Comment: UB is UB.  You read off the end of an array and wild and interesting things occur.  Perhaps the array had more room.  Alignment changes?  Good/Bad Luck...

Comment: @EnzoNakamura It is probably something to do with optimization. One version keeps working because the value was in a register and it ignored you overwriting it in memory. Maybe. As Michael says, undefined behavior.

Comment: @EnzoNakamura: Hi. The first version doesn't work for my either (using gcc 6.3.0). The vital point is that the address of `matrix` is being overwritten, so - even if the first loop doesn't cause a segmentation fault - that's just a coincidence.
The first version might not segfault, but have you tried reading the values from `matrix` afterwards?

Comment: Ok, something really weird is going on.

@DavidCollins, I printed the matrices with the first version loop (without the '%3' in fscanf). It prints correctly.

I realized that the '%3' in fscanf got away with the segmentation fault in my computer. However, the program prints the matrices wrongly (with both versions of for-loop). So maybe some kind of UB is still up?

Yet, after I read the line of *** with fscanf(path_matr, " %3[^\n]", line), I did printf("%s\n", line) and it only printed '*'. I did printf("%d\n", line[0]) and it printed negative number.

Any ideas someone?

Comment: Just to let things clearer: the code I posted here is part of another code, from which I removed some blocks (such as checking the number of arguments, fopen's return, etc) for simplicity. The issues I describe here also happens with the original code.

Comment: @EnzoNakamura: I think you are using wide characters for the separator. I have updated my answer. Try using the standard `*` ASCII character.

Comment: @DavidCollins: Thank you! That was the problem. I copied and pasted the input from the assignment.